# zookeeper cluster Cannot assign requested address (Bind failed) ERROR[ListenerHandler]

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to build zookeeper cluster of 3 nodes in AWS. All 3 nodes has public ip's and available by public ip. Can not start zookeeper due to this error. Ports are available. Myid present on each node 1,2,3.
I even tried enabling and disabling the firewall and ports, change servers addresses to 0.0.0.0 but nothing helps.

```
[myid:1] ERROR[ListenerHandler-/3.66.164.46:3888:QuorumCnxManager$Listener$ListenerHandler@1112
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address (Bind failed)
[myid:1] - INFO  [QuorumPeerListener:QuorumCnxManager$Listener@979] - Leaving listener
[myid:1] - ERROR [QuorumPeerListener:QuorumCnxManager$Listener@981] - As I'm leaving the listener 
[myid:1] - ERROR [QuorumPeerListener:ServiceUtils@42] - Exiting JVM with code 14
```

My configuration:

```
zoo.cfg
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper

clientPort=2181
clientPortAddress=0.0.0.0
autopurge.purgeInterval=1
autopurge.snapRetainCount=5
maxClientCnxns=10


server.1=3.66.164.46:2888:3888
server.2=54.93.51.11:2888:3888
server.3=3.65.56.192:2888:3888

zookeeper.service
[Unit]
Description=Zookeeper Daemon
Documentation=http://zookeeper.apache.org
Requires=network.target
After=network.target

[Service]    
Type=forking
WorkingDirectory=/opt/zookeeper
User=zookeeper
Group=zookeeper
ExecStart=/opt/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh start-foreground /opt/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg
ExecStop=/opt/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh stop /opt/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg
ExecReload=/opt/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh restart /opt/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg
TimeoutSec=30
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Ports check:

```
    sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      576/sshd            
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      576/sshd            
tcp6       0      0 :::44379                :::*                    LISTEN      24787/java          
tcp6       0      0 :::2181                 :::*                    LISTEN      24787/java          
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      24787/java
```

/etc/hosts

```
3.66.164.46 lx1 ip-172-20-98-26.eu-central-1.compute.internal
54.93.51.11 lx2 ip-172-20-111-50.eu-central-1.compute.internal
3.65.56.192 lx3 ip-172-20-111-50.eu-central-1.compute.internal
```

Can not telnet by this ports to other nodes.

```
telnet 3.66.164.46 2888
Trying 3.66.164.46...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

telnet 3.66.164.46 3888
Trying 3.66.164.46...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```